# Two Factor Authentication System

Tags: php, security

I'm trying to design a two factor authentication system (on PHP) using SMS as the second auth method. This is for a test project thus can anyone help me to design this service?

This will be an web based system and below is what i have done so far.

1. Once the client enters the Username and Password the website will send a secure HTTP request to our server with the MSISDN, a UID (to identify the session), their UserID & PassWord.
2. Our server will add the request to a MySQL DB and respond the website with a Code, UID and some other info.
3. Our server will send the client a SMS with the one time password.
4. Once the client enters the OTP into the website, the website will send another HTTPS request with the encrypted OTP to our server and we will send a success or fail code as the response.

this is the flow i have thought about. Anyone have a better flow? or suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Sounds interesting, as far as a flow for authentication: if user dropoff is not a concern or security and/or spam prevention is a high concern I'd say this is fine. Craigslist has recently begun requiring authentication with SMS messages and a valid US-based telephone number.

Comment: Ya, this is for a local bank in Sri Lanka thus i should not worry about spammers i suppose :) but yes i can always add a CAPTCHA object in the initial authentication form or at the OTP form. Thanks for the thought mate .... :)

Comment: As I said in my answer, this isnt 2factor authentication... Btw, you can also try asking as http://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a valid mechanism.  But what if the SMS device is not in a service area?  Or dead battery?

Comment: or even worse they don't have a mobile phone.

Comment: @Ben: in that case, I assume there would not be a registered SMS device, so that part of the validation would not be attempted.

Comment: Correct .... All registered users must have a mobile device or a CDMA device with SMS support. Thats a basic requirement at the registration. :) But wallyk has a valid point, if the device is out of service or out of network coverage or worst if the SMS didn't get terminated at the device due to a network error. I should add an option at the second authentication form to resend the OTP and it will be a different OTP than the first. So I need to inform this to the website as well.. Thanks guys ...

Answer (score 6):

This may work fine, however **it is not two factor authentication**.

In addition to a password, a second factor can be:

- Something you have (e.g. secureid, smartcard, etc).
- Something you are (i.e. various forms of biometrics).

Since I assume you're not aiming for biometrics ;), let me clarify why I say this is not a 2nd factor (something you have).

In order to qualify as the 2nd factor, you would need to guarantee that the holder of the device (i.e. the pre-registered cellphone) is the ***only*** one who could possibly have received the SMS.
In todays cellular networks, that just aint so. There are hacks to copy e.g. a SIM card; the cellular operators can intercept; smartphones can have apps that intercept and resend; etc.
Furthermore, having the user type the code back into the website allows all the standard web attacks on that additional password: sniffing, interception, MITM, session hijacking, etc...

Now, to be clear, this still definitely has value - out of band communication *can* help ensure that the apparent user is not being victimized by a simple web attack, XSS, etc.
I've worked with a lot of telecoms that love this solution (it also happens to be part of their business model, but whatever ;) )

However, depending on your situation, some places (e.g. banks, gov't) require a real 2nd factor - i.e. cryptographic proof (usually). And this aint it.

Comment: Hay AviD, thanks for the thoughts, but as i read on the net the physical security device as the 2nd factor is not user friendly it seems as the user needs to carry another electronic device with him/her just to log in to a portal. Hence, clients prefer to have their cellphone used as the 2nd factor and this is going to be the trend according to industry experts (which i'm not) so any suggestions on how i can make my system (using the SMS) more secure? Thanks in advance mate

Comment: @megazoid, depending on circumstances, using SMS to cellphone as an out-of-band authenticator can be a very good solution (however, DO consider the economics of it, SMS is usually not free). But it is ***not*** a 2nd factor, even though it is received with a "device". For systems that require true 2-factor authentication this is not sufficient.

Comment: As per security of this system, it mostly seems good enough (for what it is). Of course dont forget SSL, encryption, secure cookies, input validation, etc etc... Also see [this question on ITsec](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/2311/33)

Answer (score 2):

I would only add that sending OTP via SMS is still considered two-factor authentication. 
The comment from Avid is clear

> 2nd factor, you would need to guarantee that the holder of the device (i.e. the pre-registered cellphone) is the only one who could possibly have received the SMS.

But, the same would apply, say, for a hardware token based 2FA. How can one guarantee the hardware token is used by only one person? Stealing a dongle (or looking up the OTP on its screen)  is even easier than intercepting SMS

@megazoid, have you considered using "2FA as a service" providers? Such as [Authy.com](https://Authy.com) , [Token2.com](https://Token2.com) or [DuoSecurity](http://DuoSecurity.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Everybody still likes SMS but in my opinion it sucks. No matter how much SMS Passcode tries to improve the workflow.

An attacker could request an SMS and intercept the SMS without the user noticing it. For this he does not even need to steal the phone.
And in my opinion this is the worst attack, since the victim will not realize, that he has been compromized.

When stealing a dongle, the user knows, that he has been compromized and the relevant counter measures can be performed.

Stealing the seed of the dongle from the vendor, is a much better attack vector, which was also shown in the past ;-)

This is why you should think of using hardware tokens, that you can seed yourself. So you can be sure, that the seed only belongs to you. Seedable tokens are the yubikey, eToken Pass and eToken NG OTP.

Anyway, for a "low security" environment even using SMS might be ok. But you need to be aware of the consequences. By the way, all those kind of tokens are supported by the open source project [privacyIDEA](http://www.privacyidea.org).

Comment: Note that NIST discarded the out of band authentication via SMS!

Answer (score 0):

I invite you to look for ideas in the clients we've open-sourced at Duo for our two-factor authentication system:

https://github.com/duosecurity/duo_web

Another place to look is existing 3rd-party authentication protocols such as OAuth and OpenID.

Two things you haven't mentioned:

- The signed response should include a user ID, for comparison with the local user (probably stored in a secure session) to avoid replays
- The signed response should include an expiration, or return a nonce given in the signed request

Comment: Hi Karl, 1. The OTP will be destroyed after a given time frame so the user needs to use the OTP within that time frame (ex. 1min) otherwise, have to request for a new OTP. Will this answer your two suggestion?

Comment: If I understand you right, the *response* from the server, which indicates whether the given OTP passed or failed, must be protected.  I recommend looking at, and/or using, 3rd-party auth protocols (which is what you're doing even if you're filling the roles of the auth consumer and provider).

Answer (score 0):

Ricky from Twilio here.

We just released a [non-trivial, production-ready example Two-Factor Authentication tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/php/laravel) that you can check out if you're looking for some inspiration for how to architect a system like this.